# IntelliJ copyright headers for SQL files

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, configuration, copyright-display

In our project we use copyright headers in all of ours source files. This would great for Java, HTML and other languages but not for SQL files.

Does anybody know how we can use the IntelliJ copyright headers in SQL files?

Comment: Currently it is not possible for sql files: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215615

Comment: @Andrey you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In 2019.2 version it is not possible for sql files: [IDEA-215615](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215615)

**UPD**: the support will be added in 2019.3 version.

Comment: Are you sure? The issue is not mentioned in the release notes.

Comment: Sorry it was not included into 2019.3 version. Should appear in 2019.3.1 (builds >= 193.5590).